# Retrieve path parameters with Jersey from the request object

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a REST API call using Jersey, like this:

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/get/{version}")
public String getData(@PathParam("version") String version, FormDataMultiPart request) {

    // My code here
}
```

The fact is that I want both:

```
 1) The version set into the URL (like it is now)
 2) The version retrieved from the request object.
 I don't want to have two separate inputs.
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are firing a request using jQuery and AJAX, this is how you can do it:

```
var vesrion = <retrieve vesrion>
var requestURL = "http://required.url/" + version

$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : rquestURL,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            data : new FormData($("#"+formId)[0]) // 'formId' will be the ID of your form           
       }) ..
```

This is how you can pass both path param and form data together.

Comment: It can be any clients, so I don't think this gonna work. For example a simple rest client in the browser.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by "I don't want to have two separate inputs." ?